# How do I pass parameter to a rake task that is invoked using Rake::Task

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here is my rake task

```
task :lab => :enviroment do 
  Rake::Task["db:rollback"].invoke('STEP=5')
end
```

It is not doing what I want. What I want is

```
rake db:rollback STEP=5
```

I am using Rails 3.2.1 on ruby 1.9.2.

On the command line I want to execute

```
rake lab
```

The real case is much more complicated but this is the jist.

Answer (score 4):

```
task :lab => :enviroment do 
  ENV['STEP'] ||= 5
  Rake::Task["db:rollback"].invoke
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Options can be passed into rake by specifying key/value pairs on the rake command:

```
rake options:show opt1=value1
```

These command line options are then automatically set as environment variables which can be accessed within your rake task:

```
namespace :options do

  desc "Show how to read in command line options"
  task :show do
    p "option1 is #{ENV['opt1']}"
  end

end
```

Comment: Please see the question. Your answer is right but is not relevant to the question.

Answer (score -1):

Passing this as an environment variable might be your best bet. Try:

```
task :lab => :enviroment do 
  Rake::Task["db:rollback"].invoke(ENV['STEP'])
end

rake db:rollback STEP=5
```

Comment: I need to pass that 5 also inside the rake task. How do I do that ?

Comment: Everyone you want to use it just call ENV['STEP'] and it'll return 5.

Comment: That did NOT work because that would be like Rake::Task["db:rollback"].invoke(5). Notice `STEP` is not being passed to db:rollback